# How to write Array of data into text file from an HTTPS API call?

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems, google-cloud-firestore

I Implemented an API from the API the resultant data need to store it in a `.txt` file. When the API calls, the data should write in the `.txt` file.

This API call contains arrays of data received from the client side. The resultant is adding all the array of elements into a single array. This single array needs to be written in the file in Node.js.

My code is:

```
exports.Entry = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  var fs = require('fs');
  var a = ['6', '7', '8'];
  var b = ['22', '27', '20'];
  var eachrecord = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    eachrecord += a + b;
  }

  console.log("eachrecord is", eachrecord);

  //Writing each record value into file
  fileWriteSync('/Users/lahariareti/Desktop/deyaPaydevelopment/deyaPayandroidRETROFIT/functions/filewriting.txt');

  function fileWriteSync(filePath) {
    var fd = fs.openSync(filePath, 'w');
    var length = eachrecord.length;

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      var eachrecordwrite = fs.writeSync(fd, eachrecord[i] + '\n', null, null);

      console.log("hii", eachrecord[i]);
    }

    fs.closeSync(fd);
  }
});
```

When I deployed and tested it shows the error like:

> "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   '/Users/lahariareti/Desktop/deyaPaydevelopment/deyaPayandroidRETROFIT/functions/filewriting.txt'"

How to write data into a file from API calls using Node.js?

Answer (score 0):

> *When I deployed and tested*

I suppose you ran this code on your computer, it works because the path `/Users/lahariareti/Desktop/deyaPaydevelopment/deyaPayandroidRETROFIT/functions/` exists, then you ran the code on another computer and it doesn't work anymore?

`fs.open` with flag `w` will attempt to create the file, but will **not** create the parent directory/directories.

To avoid providing the full path without using relative paths, you may use a combination of [`__dirname`](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_dirname) and [`path.join`](https://nodejs.org/api/all.html#path_path_join_paths) like so:

```
fileWriteSync(path.join(__dirname, '../functions/filewriting.txt'));
```

Comment: Here the problem is when I call the API it should create the text file and write the data into a file. (for me the file is not at all being created).How can  I create a file in an API call

Comment: On the machine you execute this code, do these folders exist: `/Users/lahariareti/Desktop/deyaPaydevelopment/deyaPayandroidRETROFIT/functions/`? In other words, get in a shell on that machine (a server, I suppose) and type `cd /Users/lahariareti/Desktop/deyaPaydevelopment/deyaPayandroidRETROFIT/functions/`, does it set you in that `functions` directory, or does it display an error?

Comment: Though the path is the correct file is not being created.

Comment: Then there must be a mess-up with permissions for the user the code uses to run - although then the error should be a "denied" message, not "no such file or dir"...

Comment: I am not execute the code in terminal.i deployed the api and run that url in browser.